# Wordpress to other source rest calls with username / password

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, restful-authentication, wordpress-rest-api

I have been asked to create some custom content on a wordpress site, basically just some web app stuff (html/css/js), but leveraging data from another source via restcalls. There is a service account un/pwd required, and I am wondering what is best practice/approach in terms of the cross site calls with this un? The wire is encrypted but I certainly don't want to store the creds on the client (wordpress admin stuff). I am assuming there is a mechanism to store such on the 'back-end', filesystem, but I am not even sure such access exists? How you get to this....I have gone through the wordpress admin board and haven't found anything that provides access to the filesystem/php files, etc. Perhaps I am not looking in the right place or after the wrong bits?

I have googled but am such a noob with wordpress I am not even sure I have the right approach in mind; any help/advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: so if curl is the standard approach for this type of thing, where/how am I able to access the filesystem/php? Is there a specific place this type if thing lives or a convention of where it is placed? Just help with some 101 direction please.

Comment: Must this Data be "live"?
If yes, use ajax and get data with curl?

Comment: Yes interactive web app that makes calls while user is using. Thanks!

Comment: So, what do you want help with? Just how to store information in WP that will be used by your plugin/theme/whatever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you will need to develop a plugin for WordPress to properly hook into everything and play nice with everyone else. There are many tutorials for getting started. [Here's one](https://www.airpair.com/wordpress/posts/developing-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch) that integrates with an API

If you have to store things to make your plugin integrate with this third party, you should use the [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) that WP provides to you, with the information set from a settings page. *Please don't hardcode that into a file somewhere in the code.* (I'll also mention if you need something more powerful than the plugin options, you can [add custom tables](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-database-tables-for-plugins/))

Now we have code running on WordPress with the information it needs, now it needs to do something. To pull the information from this third party, we can use [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php).

Last, depending on how we want this information to end up being consumed by the user. We can do something simply such as just fetching/injecting the data during a regular WP page load on our custom page. Or we could be fancier and set up a WP REST API endpoint that re-serves the information we got from the 3rd party. Shortcodes? Widgets? Custom Templates? Filter Hooks? There is a lot of ways to present our final interface to the user.

Comment: thanks, really I want to develop custom html/css/js content within pages and use the calls directly from javascript (angularjs). I appreciate the starting points.

Comment: If you want to use a frontend framework like angularjs, then I would recommend setting up a wp rest api endpoint that is just a proxy to the 3rd party. Let WP hold onto the U/P for the 3rd party, like you said, don't store that on the client side if you don't have to.

Comment: no I certainly don't want to. All I want to do is SPA instances on wordpress pages, but most need to gather info from this other site, and all those calls use the un/pwd. So whatever mechanism for keeping that on WP and off the client is really what I am after, but I get there is a bunch of context around it that I am unware of as having never touched WP.